# Cx_oracle trigger error

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am trying to create a simple trigger in cx_oracle which copies values in a table called **Student** when some value is inserted in the table **studentTemp**. There are only two columns in each table namely stud_ID and stud_Name. When I try to insert value in StudentTemp by using

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO studentTemp VALUES(1, 'Bob')")
```

I am getting error *DatabaseError: ORA-04098: trigger 'S12345.INSERT_STUD' is invalid and failed re-validation*. Following is the code

```
cur.execute('''CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_Stud
            AFTER INSERT ON studentTemp
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO Student(Stud_ID,Stud_Name) VALUES 
                 (:new.Stud_ID, :new.Stud_Name);
            END;''')
```

I have also tried

```
cur.execute('''CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_Stud
            AFTER INSERT ON studentTemp
            REFERENCING NEW AS new
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO Student(Stud_ID,Stud_Name) VALUES (:new.Stud_ID, :new.Stud_Name);
            END;/''')
```

But still get the same error

I can get it work if I use a stored procedure like this

```
# create insertStudent() stored procedure
cur.execute('''CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertStudent(
                sID IN STUDENT.STUDENT_ID%TYPE,
                sName IN STUDENT.STUDENT_NAME%TYPE)
            IS
            BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(sID, sName);
            END;''')

# create insert_Stud() trigger
cur.execute('''CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_Stud
            AFTER INSERT ON studentTemp
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                 insertStudent(:new.Stud_ID, :new.Stud_Name);
            END;''')
```

Can someone kindly tell me how to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you have an error in naming your Student-Table Fields.

In your Procedure, the colums are referenced as

```
STUDENT.STUDENT_ID
STUDENT.STUDENT_NAME
```

In your trigger, you call them

```
INSERT INTO Student(**Stud_ID**,**Stud_Name**) VALUES ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that but its still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have the possibility to connect to the db with SQL Developer? You could then compile the trigger directly and get feedback what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL*Plus to create the trigger. Then use the "show errors" command to see what the problem is. After that you should be able to use cx_Oracle without any difficulty. The only difference is that the trailing / in SQL*Plus does not need to be there.